# Google image from cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, google-image-search

I'd like to write a program in cocoa that parse a google image webpage and extract the images.
i use a code like this:

```
NSURL *url = [ NSURL URLWithString: [ NSString stringWithFormat: @"https://www.google.it/search?q=%@&tbm=isch", searchString] ];
NSStringEncoding enc;
NSString *test = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url usedEncoding:&enc error:NULL];
```

The problem is that the page that is returned in this way is different from what it is in a browser.
I'don't get the imgurl parameter with the url of the full image. only the thumbnails.
There is a way to have the complete google images results in cocoa like i have in firefox?
Thank you

Comment: check my answer.. your problem solved...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is not correct way.

To get list of images, you should use [Google API for image Search](https://developers.google.com/image-search/v1/jsondevguide)

Follow below link for more details.

https://developers.google.com/image-search/v1/jsondevguide

The URL for webservice would look like below.

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?q=soccer&v=1.0
                                                          ^^^^^^ your search keyword here...
```

Comment: api is deprecated